# How can I connect to multiple independent networks at the same time?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking

I have two independent networks, one is wireless with the details:

Range: 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.0.1

And one which is wired with the details:

Range: 192.168.1.1 to 192.168.1.255
Subnet Mask: 255.255.255.0
Default Gateway: 192.168.1.1
*No internet access*

Both networks give IP's using DHCP and both have a router.

I’m having a problem using both networks at the same time.

When both adapters are enabled I can access the wired network’s resources but not the internet through the wireless network. Strangely however, I can access the configuration panels of both routers.

When doing a ping on an external URL, it appears that DNS is working (I resolve an IP address) but I get 100% loss.

If I disable the wired network, all internet connectivity comes back immediately.

I have a feeling that internet request are heading to the wired router only to time out.

Is what I am trying to achieve possible? It seems like it should be. If it is, how do I set it up correctly?

Comment: Do both networks really use the same 192.168.0/24 subnet? Your wired network example has a gateway in 192.168.1/24, but addresses in 192.168.0/24

Comment: This is an error with typing it out. Wired is 192.168.1.x, wireless is 192.168.0.x.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wired connection is configured with a default gateway that's inaccessible through your IP Address/Subnet mask configuration.

Change the wired gateway to 192.168.0.1 (or whatever that does routing for the wired connection, here i'm assuming the wireless router is the same one you've connected through wired).

EDIT:
As answer was solved in the comments below, the following comment is deemed useful in solving the problem:

> Is the Draytek connected to the internet? It could be that if it's
>   not, the metric for default gateway on the wired network is more
>   preferred than the wireless. You could try to remove the default
>   gateway on the wired network (if it's not supposed to access the
>   internet).

Comment: Idiot me, I've edited the post to reflect the actual IP address range.

Comment: What is then on 192.168.1.1 - what device is on that address doing the routing for you?

Comment: A Draytek Vigor 2800.

Comment: Is the Draytek connected to the internet? It could be that if it's not, the metric for default gateway on the wired network is more preferred than the wireless. You could try to remove the default gateway on the wired network (if it's not supposed to access the internet).

Comment: It isn't connected to the internet. I'll try to remove it now.

Comment: Following instructions on http://superuser.com/q/77822/79349, I have set the wired adapter to have a high metric. This has solved my issue. I will accept this as the answer but you should edit above to reflect the actual problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have successfully joined my network with this kind of situation. A wireless router and a switch. they can be joined together with internet connection. I got this setup by discovery and implemented it in our company. It works for us!

My networking equipment are **Linksys 2024 24 port switch**, **Juniper firewall** and **Linksys WRT610N Wireless router**.

Here is my setup and configuration:

[image]

1. Connect the Network Switch to a firewall.
2. Configure your wireless router and change the defualt IP to 192.168.0.x, where x is the available IP for internet connection.
3. Connect the Wireless router to the network switch (for the switch, any port is ok, while for wireless router, use the internet port).
4. Connect another lan cable to wireless router's port and the network switch port.
5. Now, when you connect to the wireless network, get to know the ip address, then replace it with any ip address in range of 192.168.0.1 to 192.168.0.255.
6. After you change your Wireless PC's ip address, go to the firewall setup, through policy, set the ip address to acquire access to the internet.

Read More:[Joining Wireless Network to Wired Network Effectively with Internet Connection](http://windowsreality.blogspot.com/2012/01/joining-wireless-router-to-network.html)